# How can I add a footer to Kotlin Dokka docs?

Tags: kotlin, footer, kotlin-dokka

I am looking for a way to include text in the footer of all Dokka generated docs. I am not seeing this option being advertised by the Gradle or Maven plugins for Dokka.

Is this possible? Can you point me to a sample?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your own footer by overriding the Dokka footer message.

*{module}/build.gradle*

```
tasks.named("dokkaHtml").configure {
  pluginsMapConfiguration.set(
    [
      "org.jetbrains.dokka.base.DokkaBase": """{
        "footerMessage": "Your New Footer!"
      }"""
    ]
  )
}
```

This will replace the `Copyright 20xx` in the current footer.
For further details on multi-module / css support, recommend checking out the source below.

Source: [Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30067669-documenting-kotlin-code-for-android-using-kdoc-and-dokka#toc-anchor-016)

Comment: Does anyone have documentation showing all they keys we can set here? I know that Ray W. link shows `footerMessage` and `customStyleSheets`, but is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

**There are two instance methods in `dokka` package – one for `footer`, one for `header`**:

```
fun appendFooter(to:) { }

fun appendHeader(to:, title:, basePath:) { }
```

> Here's a [real code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dokka/+/244f97fc9ec5745b377e594e54b2f465489fef8b%5E1..244f97fc9ec5745b377e594e54b2f465489fef8b/) how it looks like:

```
package org.jetbrains.dokka

import java.io.File

interface HtmlTemplateService {

    fun appendHeader(to: StringBuilder, title: String?, basePath: File)
    fun appendFooter(to: StringBuilder)

    companion object {

        fun default(css: String? = null): HtmlTemplateService {
            return object : HtmlTemplateService {

                override fun appendFooter(to: StringBuilder) {
                    if (!to.endsWith('\n')) {
                        to.append('\n')
                    }
                    to.appendln("</BODY>")
                    to.appendln("</HTML>")
                }
                override fun appendHeader(to: StringBuilder, title: String?, basePath: File) {
                    to.appendln("<HTML>")
                    to.appendln("<HEAD>")
                    to.appendln("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">")
                    if (title != null) {
                        to.appendln("<title>$title</title>")
                    }
                    if (css != null) {
                        val cssPath = basePath.resolve(css)
                        to.appendln("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"$cssPath\">")
                    }
                    to.appendln("</HEAD>")
                    to.appendln("<BODY>")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> I think it must be working even in [dokka.playground](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/blob/master/test/playground.kt).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking at. Your first link points to a commit log, the second to a test file. The code you include is an interface with a companion object - how is that called from gradle?

Comment: The main link is first one (the second link is just an example showing that you might test this code in Dokka playground). And, honestly, I don't realise how to call it from gradle... That's all that I could find on Dokka's footer.

Comment: I'm sorry this is not meeting the criteria of the bounty :| Thanks for your help.